# MySQL Workbench - Is Standard (TCP/IP) over Standard TCP/IP over SSH preferred?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is Standard (TCP/IP) a faster or more secure method to connect than Standard TCP/IP over SSH preferred?  I am wondering if both options are available which one I should choose (if that matters anyways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP/IP over SSH should be more secure. Standard TCP/IP should be faster as there's no encryption involved but is less secure.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your usage pattern, with a grain of salt, by enabling SSH you trade security for CPU cycles, so:

- If you work on localhost DO NOT use SSH (but nothing bad will happen, if you do)
- If you work across the internet DO use SSH (or bad things may happen if you dont)
- If you work in your LAN decide according to Common Sense (TM)